# Disable HP PC Hardware Diagnostics UEFI in Ubuntu

Tags: uefi, hardware, bios

I had the Windows 8 operating system and I just installed ubuntu 16, then I put the boot options by default but when I turn on my laptop the F2 option always appears immediately: "HP PC Hardware Diagnostics UEFI" and I can not access the desktop. If I put: Secure Boot as Disabled in the BIOS I can access the desktop but only after the F2 option appears.

Could someone please explain to me why this option appears and what can I do in ubuntu so that it does not appear? It is something that also appeared when I used windows (after turning on my laptop and before accessing the desktop). Thank you very much.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puw9o.jpg)

Comment: Can you try to push Hardware Diagnostics to the bottom in the UEFI boot order? Probably it's at the top now.

Comment: Thanks, but this option does not exist in the UEFI boot order. If you mean "OS boot manager" this does not solve the problem.